# Python, if integer equals number

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

I'm an animator who is new to programming and I was wondering how to compare if a variable is equal to multiple numbers at once.

My code thus far:::

```
if intJoints==(3, 4, 6, 10):
    animValue=3
animValue=4
```

A formula for a 3D character I am animating always evaluates as "4" unless the character has 3, 4 , 6, or 10 joints in its spine.(Then it evaluates to "3" for some reason)
Can I check all those values at once without making many "if" statement lines?

This syntax isn't working, it probably thinks I'm writing a tuple or something...
Thank you for your help. Probably super basic to a pro coder, but it's actually hard to get a clear answer on basic stuff like this...
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually want to use the `in` keyword here.

The correct syntax is

```
if intJoints in (3, 4, 6, 10):
```

You *could* do something like

```
if intJoints == 3 or intJoints == 4 or intJoints == 6 or intJoints == 10
```

but obviously using the `in` keyword is more concise and readable here.

Your original syntax

```
intJoints==(3, 4, 6, 10)
```

tests to see whether `intJoints` is equal to *the entire tuple*. The only way this could possibly be true is if `intJoints` literally equals `(3, 4, 6, 10)`.